# How do I create a class using inputs from previous classes?

Tags: python, class

I have 2 simple classes: 'Student' and 'Module' containing student names and module codes, respectively. I'm trying to make a third class called 'Registration' with no inputs but with the method 'add' so I can add records to say a student is registered on this module or visa versa... So far I have this:

```
class Student:  
    'Class to define student details'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

class Module:   
    'Class to define module codes'
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
    def getCode(self):
        return self.code

class Registration(Student, Module):
    'Class telling us what modules students are taking'
    reglist = []
    def __init__(self):
        Student.__init__(self, name)
        Module.__init__(self, code)
    def add(self, details):
        self.reglist.append(details)
```

To test it I need to be able to use the following to get the specified output:

```
r = Registrations()
r.add(james,agm)
r.add(alice,agm)
r.add(alice,ipp)

mstr = ''
for m in map(str,r.modules(alice)):
    mstr = mstr+' '+m
print(alice, 'is doing the following modules:', mstr)
sstr = ''
for s in map(str,r.students(agm)):
    sstr = sstr+' '+s
print(agm, 'has the following students:', sstr)

print(r)
```

How would I go about making my Registration class to have the functions to 'add' students and modules and then return the set of students for a module and then return the set of modules taken by one student? If that makes sense, please help I'm a Python newbie and having so much trouble with more complex classes :(

Comment: Are you sure this is the class hierarchy you'd like to use? Do you really feel `Registration` *is a* `Student` and *is a* `Module`?

Comment: `Registration` should have an `__init__()` method that takes no arguments other than the default one usually called `self`. This method should simply set `self.reglist = []` so each instance of the class has an initially empty registration list for its `add()` method to populate. Most importantly, it should not be derived from the other two classes since it's not an "is_a" of either one.

Comment: You should read what OOP is.
A Registration is NOT a Student AND a Module.
A registration is a registration. Why do you inherit from two classes? The design is wrong. Design your data model first, then you can think about the implementation.

Comment: Registration has-a student, and has-a Module.  Not is-a Student (or Module).

Comment: Also, perhaps you meant `'james','agm'` instead of `james,agm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in a dictionary, and do it this way:

```
class Registration():
    'Class telling us what modules students are taking'
    def __init__(self):
        self.regdict = {}
    def add(self, name, module):
        self.regdict.setdefault(name, []).append(Modules(module))
    def modules(self, name):
        return self.regdict[name]
```

However, as others mentioned, you need a better understanding of classes and the use of it. I'd suggest you to read some more about classes, and redesign your program structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that really helped! I've been reading about classes but there's nothing that has helped me with this question unfortunately. I can make simple classes but I'm not sure how to implement them into another class.

Comment: Sure, your answer helped me figure out the part I was struggling with thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class that has two methods, one of which is `__init__()`, [you're doing it wrong](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). (Please watch this video. It contains very good advice on design.)

In this case, just put an `register_student()` method in the Module class. 
To register for a class is a verb, not a noun.

If a record usually doesn't have to be modified once it is created you can use a tuple instead of a class. E.g. if the module class were a tuple consisting of the module code and a list of student, you could not change the module code, but you could modify the list of students.

```
In [1]: module = ('Algebra 101', 24, [])

In [2]: module[2].append('John Doe')

In [3]: module[2].append('Jane Doe')

In [4]: module
Out[4]: ('Algebra 101', 24, ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'])
```

It would probably be easier to read if you use `collections.namedtuple()`:

```
In [5]: from collections import namedtuple

In [6]: Module = namedtuple('Module', ['name', 'code', 'students'])

In [7]: a = Module('Algebra 101', 24, ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'])

In [8]: a
Out[8]: Module(name='Algebra 101', code=24, students=['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'])

In [9]: a.name
Out[9]: 'Algebra 101'

In [10]: a.students
Out[10]: ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
```

Additionally, *in general* you don't need get and set methods in Python classes for simple properties like a name. Unless you want to do additional things like validate input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the question requires me to use classes and also says that I need to make 3 classes, 2 simple Student and Module ones which I have, and a 3rd more complex class Registrations which is the one I am struggling with. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: At a guess, your instructor has been sipping too much Java. :-)